# Find the length, width and height of the box

Tags: mathematics

I have a box.
Ratio of length, width and height of the box is $a:b:c$.
Ratio of sum of all 12 edges' length, surface area (all 6 sides) and volume is also $a:b:c$
Find the length, width and height of the box.

Note:

> $a$, $b$ and $c$ are integers and can be the same number.

Comment: Downvotes, and votes to close this? Why? Tell me the reason, so I will not post the puzzle like this again.

Comment: Is there any way to find the answer ?? or just trial and error method ??

Comment: @Amaruth : Math to find some candidate, and a bit of calculation between the candicate, will come to the right answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but voted to close as this is a typical math textbook problem, thus offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

> $a=3$, $b=12$, $c=12$ works well.

Check:

> Sum of all the edges' length: $4\times(a+b+c)=4\times(3+12+12)=4\times27=108$
> Surface: $2\times(a\times b+a\times c+b\times c)=2\times(3\times12+3\times12+12\times12)=$
> $=2\times(36+36+144)=2\times216=432$
> Volume: $a\times b\times c=3\times12\times12=432$
>
>  $3:12:12=108:432:432$

How to find this:

> The four equations can be written as:
>  $4\times(a+b+c)=k\times a$
>  $2\times(a\times b+a\times c+b\times c)=k\times b$
>  $a\times b\times c=k\times c$
>
>  From the last one, we immediately get $k=ab$.
>  Using this on the second one, we get $c=\frac{a^2 b}4-a-b$.
>  All this turns the first equation into $b^2(-\frac{a^2}4+\frac{a}2+1)+b(-\frac{a^3}4+a)+a^2=0$
>
>  The square root of the discriminant has to be a rational number, so $a^4+8a^2-32a-48$ has to be a perfect square.

Comment: 2 same answer, but I will choose @elias answer as accepted, because elias is the first person answering rightly

Answer (score 0):

Possible

> a = 3, b = 12, c = 12

so,

> a = 3, b = 12, c = 12
>
>  P=108, A = 432, V = 432
>
>  P:A:V = a:b:c

Answer (score -1):

Solve the below eqn -

> 4a + 4b +4c =ak ; 2ab +2bc+2ca =bk ;abc=ck

So , ab =k

Comment: you forgot a factor in all the equations

Comment: @elias the factor gets cancelled on both sides

Comment: it does not! the right sides of your three equations all need the same factor added

Comment: @elias they how did you find answer

Comment: After introducing the factor, you can start eliminating the variables. First $k$, then $c$. After that you get a quadratic equation for $b$, with parameter $a$.